# WPF Menu: Wrap items

Tags: wpf, menu, menuitem

I'm working on a WPF control that gets placed inside a TabControl in another window, and I have a menu that stretches across the top of my custom control with the letters of the alphabet as such (for indexing purposes):

```
<UserControl x:Class="thispageclass"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d">
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
            <Menu Name="mnu">
                <MenuItem Header="A" />
                <MenuItem Header="B" />
                <MenuItem Header="C" />
                ...
                <MenuItem Header="Y" />
                <MenuItem Header="Z" />
            </Menu>

            [other elements]
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

If all the letters are present, the menu gets wider than the window so you can't see the last few items without making the window wider. It seems like it should be trivial to make the menu wrap around if the window is too small but I can't seem to figure out how.

Comment: What sort of container(s) is your `Menu` element in?  I am getting wrapping behavior in both a `StackPanel` and `DockPanel`, with the code you provided.

Comment: @Merlyn: Right now it's in a vertical StackPanel with some other elements. I tried putting it inside both its own StackPanel and DockPanel with no luck.

Comment: You're going to have to provide even more code, because I still get good wrapping behavior with the code you provided, following an example that matches your description.  I have inside my main window a `Grid` with a `TabControl`, inserted a `TabItem`, and in its content, I put an instance of your control.  For "[other elements]", I added a `TextBox`.  It didn't exhibit the problem you describe.  You'll need to give us something that repros the problem.  You'll probably figure out where you're going wrong while you're trying to cut down your code...

Comment: @Merlyn - I also created my own minimal sample which worked, leading me to figuring out it was my custom styles that were messing up my menu. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created my own minimal sample which worked, leading me to figuring out it was my custom styles that were messing up my menu.

Answer (score 3):

Just override the [ItemsPanel](http://www.wpfwiki.com/WPF%20Q9.4.ashx) of your Menu to a WrapPanel

**Sample**

```
    <Menu.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <WrapPanel/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </Menu.ItemsPanel>
```

Comment: It should work..Try setting a width for your usercontrol or window

Comment: <WrapPanel ItemWidth="200" MaxWidth="800"/>